# Android Maps custom marker InfoWindow

Tags: android, image, google-maps, infowindow, markers

Is it possible to insert a picture into an info window?

I have about 20 markers on my map and would like a different picture for each marker. The markers also all have different Titles and Snippets.

At the moment I add a marker like :

```
 mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(
     new LatLng(location)).title("Marker1")
    .snippet("Snippet 1") .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(blue)));
```

I would like to add an image to the left of the text in the infoWindow. What is the best way to go about this?

Thank you

Comment: The [Google Maps Util Library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/utility/)  might be a good place to start. It provides helpers for creating Markers.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to read article about [Google Maps markers](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/marker). And you will need to create your own `InfoWindowAdapter()` and use `getInfoContents()` or `getInfoWindow()` to return the info window contents containing the image you seek.